# How to call a function localStorage.setItem from PHP with string special char (eg. email adr)

Tags: local-storage, special-characters

The code below is having a problem with the special characters. Does anybody know why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function enter_user_email(str){
   localStorage.setItem('user_email', str);
}
</script>

<?php
$usr_email= "aaaaaa@bbbbb.xx";
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">enter_user_email(\"$usr_email\");</script>";
?>
```

Comment: what kind of problem does occur? just guessing: could it be that for interpolating variables with a name containing underscores you have to enclose it in curly braces (`\"${usr_email}\"`) ?

Comment: placed the function call into curly braces -> same result.
Result is as follows: 
-> the PHP call to the javascript function is failing and it echoes the following 3 chars: ***");***
(the 3 last chars from to call to the function)
 I think, because of the special chars in $usr_email the call Fails. If i delete the "." and/or the "@" the call works perfect.